A classical theorem on product of Borel sigma algebras
Theorem Let $n\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n\geq 2$ and let $r\in \mathbb{Z}\cap [1,n-1]$. Then, we have that
$$\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^r)\otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{n-r})=\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$$
Proof.
$(\supseteq)$
Define $n$-interval the product of $n$ open intervals of $\mathbb{R}$ (with respect to the euclidean topology).
It's simple to see that every $n$-interval can be written as a product of a $r$-interval and a $(n-r)$-interval. So, a $n$-interval is an element of $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^r)\otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{n-r})$. Moreover, exists a countable base for the euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$ given by open $n$-intervals and so the euclidean topology itself is contained in $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^r)\otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{n-r})$. So, $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)\subseteq \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^r)\otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{n-r})$.
$(\subseteq)$
Define the following families:
$\Sigma_1=\{E\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{r}),\quad E\times \mathbb{R}^{n-r}\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{n}) \}$
that is a sigma algebra on $\mathbb{R}^r$ that contains the euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}^r$. So, $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{r})\subseteq \Sigma_1$.
$\Sigma_2=\{E\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{n-r}),\quad \mathbb{R}^{r}\times E\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{n}) \}$
that is a sigma algebra on $\mathbb{R}^{n-r}$ that contains the euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}^{n-r}$. So, $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{n-r})\subseteq \Sigma_2$.
So, we have that if $E_1\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{r})$ and $E_2\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{n-r})$, then
$$E_1\times E_2=(E_1\times \mathbb{R}^{n-r})\cap (\mathbb{R}^r\times E_2)\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$$ by definition of $\Sigma_1,\Sigma_2$.
This, allows to conclude because $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ contains the family $\mathcal{R}(\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{r}),\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{n-r}))$ (the measurable rectangles) and so we obtain that $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^r)\otimes \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{n-r})\subseteq \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$
Edit: changed union to intersection as suggested.

You seem to be concluding $E_1 \times E_2 \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$ from the fact $E_1\times E_2$ is a subset of an element of $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, but this is not correct. However, this is easily fixed by noting $E_1 \times E_2 = (E_1 \times \mathbb{R}^{n-r}) \cap (\mathbb{R}^r \times E_2)$ instead.

It's almost correct. I believe what you meant was that $E_1 \times E_2 = (E_1 \times \mathbb{R}^{n-r}) \cap ( \mathbb{R}^{r} \times E_2) \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, and then the rest follows as is.

Thank you all!!

nice username, mate

yours is a nice name too!
